# Show compiler warnings without editing pom.xml

Tags: maven, compiler-warnings

I would like to always show compiler warning and deprecation when I compile with Maven. I know how to do it by editing the `pom.xml`, but I want this behavior by default only for myself (so I can't edit the `pom.xml`).

I tried:

```
mvn -Dmaven.compiler.showWarnings=true -Dmaven.compiler.showDeprecation=true clean compile
```

but this doesn't show any warnings (if I modify the `pom.xml` to show them, they are there).

Both expressions (`maven.compiler.showWarnings` and `maven.compiler.showDeprecation`) [exist](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html#showWarnings).

What do I miss?

Comment: Which version of maven and maven compiler plugin are you using?  This works fine for me with maven-3.0.3 and maven compiler plugin 2.3.2

Comment: @Raghuram: tried again on a minimal project, with clean installs of 2.2.1 and 3.0.3. Warnings don't show up (deprecations do).

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
mvn clean install -Dmaven.compiler.showDeprecation=true -Dmaven.compiler.showWarnings=true > warnings.txt
```

Comment: Whoever down-voted this should comment on the reasons. Looks good and worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You could perhaps wrap these in a maven profile, and instead specific the profile with -P.

It would be something like this (I did not test this though):

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>development</id>
        <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <!-- compiler options go here -->
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

And then run as

```
mvn compile -Pdebug
```